# Missing type arguments for map literal. Try adding an explicit type, or remove implicit-dynamic from your analysis options file

Tags: firebase, flutter

````
```return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('guestbook').add({
      'text': message,
      'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      'name': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.displayName,
      'userId': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
    });```
````

****Please help in solving the error****

Comment: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('guestbook').add(Map<String, dynamic>{...});`